# Having issues with using FastPCS to detect outliers

Tags: r, dataframe, row, outliers

I'm using the function FastPCS to detect outliers in a large multivariate dataset. When I get the results from this function they appear in $best as the row number the data came from. How do I take this row number and use it to get the data that was in that row in the original data frame?

```
install.packages("FastPCS")
library(FastPCS)
u = FastPCS(ft[,2:11],alpha = .75)
```

ft being a large multivariate data frame.

Comment: If `ft` is not part of the example dataset in `FastPCS` then you should edit your question to use a dataset that will be available.

Answer (score 0):

Using `iris` as my example

```
library(FastPCS)
u = FastPCS(iris,alpha = .75)

head(u$best)
[1] 76  2  3  4  5  6

head(iris[u$best,])

   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
76          6.6         3.0          4.4         1.4 versicolor
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa
6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa
```